# What is the word that describes the middle part of a presentation?

Tags: word-choice, lexicon

My presentation has three parts.

I want to use "prologue" and "epilogue" to say part 1 is the introduction and part 3 is the conclusion of a presentation.

I am wondering if there is a specialist term that I can use to describe part 2, which is the middle part of the presentation.

**EDIT**
I know "development" is another option, as is "body" from the answer below. However, I am looking for a word that is more in the tradition of [prologue, something, epilogue] i.e. fits in semantically as well as intuitively.

Answer (score 7):

The **body**.

Merriam-Webster:

> the main, central, or principal part: as (1) :  the nave of a church (2) :  the bed or box of a vehicle on or in which the load is placed (3) :  the enclosed or partly enclosed part of an automobile

eg.

> The *body* of my presentation consisted of me showing the audience photos I'd taken during my vacation, and explaining what camera filters I'd used. In my conclusion I suggested that they too should visit New Zealand.

Comment: [Kelly Garton](http://kellygarton.com/tag/introduction/) would seem to agree (though I'm not too sure about the lettuce, cheese and pickle).

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for a word that is more in the tradition of [prologue, something, epilogue]. I am updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there isn't such word coming from Greek via Latin and French.  When the subject is a novel, you can use "prologue", "main portion of the novel", "epilogue" and also "foreword" or "afterword" if you find necessary. I'm not sure what kind of presentation you mean, but remember that prologue and epilogue are only used in fiction.